# Trouble with sound in C# morse code app, string not returning and trouble with audio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console, morse-code

So my morse code app I am coding in C# is having trouble with sound and string return. I am setting up to play the repsecive wav file for each morse code letter while translating user input to morse code, but although each .wav file is imported to the Visual Studio project, only the .wav file for the letter z plays.

Also, when attempting to return the translated string, I am getting a Null Reference Exception. Here is the code

```
Dictionary<char, MorseMapping> _morseAlphabetDictionary = new Dictionary<char, MorseMapping>()
        {
            { 'a', new MorseMapping(".-", @"C:\Users\keife\source\repos\MorseCodeTranslator\MorseCodeTranslator\AnyConv.com__A_morse_code.wav") },                //.. here goes  the rest
            

        { 'b', new MorseMapping("-...", @"C:\Users\keife\source\repos\MorseCodeTranslator\MorseCodeTranslator\AnyConv.com__B_morse_code.wav") },      //.. here goes  the rest

            { 'c', new MorseMapping("-.-.", @"C:\Users\keife\source\repos\MorseCodeTranslator\MorseCodeTranslator\AnyConv.com__C_morse_code.wav") },
            //.. here goes  the rest

            { 'd', new MorseMapping("-..", @"C:\Users\keife\source\repos\MorseCodeTranslator\MorseCodeTranslator\AnyConv.com__D_morse_code.wav") },

            { 'e', new MorseMapping(".", @"C:\Users\keife\source\repos\MorseCodeTranslator\MorseCodeTranslator\AnyConv.com__E_morse_code.wav") },
            { 'f', new MorseMapping("..-.", @"C:\Users\keife\source\repos\MorseCodeTranslator\MorseCodeTranslator\AnyConv.com__F_morse_code.wav") },

            { 'g', new MorseMapping("--.", @"C:\Users\keife\source\repos\MorseCodeTranslator\MorseCodeTranslator\AnyConv.com__G_morse_code.wav") },

            { 'h', new MorseMapping("....", @"C:\Users\keife\source\repos\MorseCodeTranslator\MorseCodeTranslator\AnyConv.com__H_morse_code.wav") },
            //.. here goes  the rest


            { 'i', new MorseMapping("..", @"C:\Users\keife\source\repos\MorseCodeTranslator\MorseCodeTranslator\AnyConv.com__I_morse_code.wav") },
            //.. here goes  the rest

            { 'j', new MorseMapping(".---", @"C:\Users\keife\source\repos\MorseCodeTranslator\MorseCodeTranslator\AnyConv.com__J_morse_code.wav") },
            //.. here goes  the rest

            { 'k', new MorseMapping("-.-", @"C:\Users\keife\source\repos\MorseCodeTranslator\MorseCodeTranslator\AnyConv.com__K_morse_code.wav") },

            { 'l', new MorseMapping(".-..", @"C:\Users\keife\source\repos\MorseCodeTranslator\MorseCodeTranslator\AnyConv.com__L_morse_code.wav") },
            { 'm', new MorseMapping("--", @"C:\Users\keife\source\repos\MorseCodeTranslator\MorseCodeTranslator\AnyConv.com__M_morse_code.wav") },

            { 'n', new MorseMapping("-.", @"C:\Users\keife\source\repos\MorseCodeTranslator\MorseCodeTranslator\AnyConv.com__n_morse_code.wav") },
            { 'o', new MorseMapping("---", @"C:\Users\keife\source\repos\MorseCodeTranslator\MorseCodeTranslator\AnyConv.com__O_morse_code.wav") },
            //.. here goes  the rest


            { 'p', new MorseMapping(".--.", @"C:\Users\keife\source\repos\MorseCodeTranslator\MorseCodeTranslator\AnyConv.com__P_morse_code.wav") },
            //.. here goes  the rest

            { 'q', new MorseMapping("--.-", @"C:\Users\keife\source\repos\MorseCodeTranslator\MorseCodeTranslator\AnyConv.com__Q_morse_code.wav") },
            //.. here goes  the rest

            { 'r', new MorseMapping(".-.", @"C:\Users\keife\source\repos\MorseCodeTranslator\MorseCodeTranslator\AnyConv.com__R_morse_code.wav") },

            { 's', new MorseMapping("...", @"C:\Users\keife\source\repos\MorseCodeTranslator\MorseCodeTranslator\AnyConv.com__S_morse_code.wav") },
            { 't', new MorseMapping("-", @"C:\Users\keife\source\repos\MorseCodeTranslator\MorseCodeTranslator\AnyConv.com__t_morse_code.wav") },

            { 'u', new MorseMapping("..-", @"C:\Users\keife\source\repos\MorseCodeTranslator\MorseCodeTranslator\AnyConv.com__U_morse_code.wav") },

            { 'v', new MorseMapping("...-", @"C:\Users\keife\source\repos\MorseCodeTranslator\MorseCodeTranslator\AnyConv.com__V_morse_code.wav") },
            //.. here goes  the rest


            { 'w', new MorseMapping(".--", @"C:\Users\keife\source\repos\MorseCodeTranslator\MorseCodeTranslator\AnyConv.com__W_morse_code.wav") },
            //.. here goes  the rest

            { 'x', new MorseMapping("-..-", @"C:\Users\keife\source\repos\MorseCodeTranslator\MorseCodeTranslator\AnyConv.com__X_morse_code.wav") },
            //.. here goes  the rest

            { 'y', new MorseMapping("-.--", @"C:\Users\keife\source\repos\MorseCodeTranslator\MorseCodeTranslator\AnyConv.com__Y_morse_code.wav") },

            { 'z', new MorseMapping("--..", @"C:\Users\keife\Desktop\morse code audio\wav\AnyConv.com__Z_morse_code.wav") },
        };

        _morseAlphabetDictionary['b'].Player.Play();
        _morseAlphabetDictionary['b'].Player.Play();
        _morseAlphabetDictionary['c'].Player.Play();
        _morseAlphabetDictionary['d'].Player.Play();
        _morseAlphabetDictionary['e'].Player.Play();
        _morseAlphabetDictionary['f'].Player.Play();
        _morseAlphabetDictionary['g'].Player.Play();
        _morseAlphabetDictionary['h'].Player.Play();
        _morseAlphabetDictionary['i'].Player.Play();
        _morseAlphabetDictionary['j'].Player.Play();
        _morseAlphabetDictionary['k'].Player.Play();
        _morseAlphabetDictionary['l'].Player.Play();
        _morseAlphabetDictionary['m'].Player.Play();
        _morseAlphabetDictionary['n'].Player.Play();
        _morseAlphabetDictionary['o'].Player.Play();
        _morseAlphabetDictionary['p'].Player.Play();
        _morseAlphabetDictionary['q'].Player.Play();
        _morseAlphabetDictionary['r'].Player.Play();
        _morseAlphabetDictionary['s'].Player.Play();
        _morseAlphabetDictionary['t'].Player.Play();
        _morseAlphabetDictionary['u'].Player.Play();
        _morseAlphabetDictionary['v'].Player.Play();
        _morseAlphabetDictionary['w'].Player.Play();
        _morseAlphabetDictionary['x'].Player.Play();
        _morseAlphabetDictionary['y'].Player.Play();
        _morseAlphabetDictionary['z'].Player.Play();
    


        //.. here goes  the rest

    }






public static string GetUserInput()
{
    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
    {
        input = input.ToLower();
    }

    return input;
}

public static string Translate(string input)
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (char character in input)
        {
            if (_morseAlphabetDictionary.ContainsKey(character))
```

// This is where the error

System.NullReferenceException
Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
occurs, the line above.

```
    {
            stringBuilder.Append(_morseAlphabetDictionary[character] + " ");
        }
        else if (character == ' ')
        {
            stringBuilder.Append("/ ");
        }
        else
        {
            stringBuilder.Append(character + " ");
        }
    }

    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

}

// Any thoughts on why this might be happening is appreciated, thank you very much.

Morse Code Mapping Class

```
using System.Media;

public class MorseMapping
{
    public string MorseLetter { get; set; }
    public SoundPlayer Player { get; set; }

    public MorseMapping(string letter, string filePath)
    {
        this.MorseLetter = letter;
        this.Player = new SoundPlayer(filePath);
            }
    }
```

Comment: This is not reproducible as its not complete code. I would suggest, stepping through it with a debugger

Comment: Couple observations here.  One is that `a` is _not_ the same as `A`.  That's ignoring localization, encoding (unicode), etc.  You may be able to fix this with `input.ToLower()`.  Two, your `z` path is different from all the others.

Comment: Oh, I only posted the part where the error occurs.Should I post the full code? Thx.

Comment: Interesting development, I tried switching the order  of the _morseAlphabetDictionary['b'].Player.Play(); (so a was on the bottom and z is on the top). It then skipped all the way so that it only played the 'a' wav  file. So it seems to be it skips all of the other wav files executed to the last one. Wonder why this is happening. Thanks.

Comment: I think we need the code behind the `MorseMapping` class.  Based on what you are saying, I would speculate that all of your audio files are playing at same time, but the code behind the `Player.Play` is stopping the play back of the audio as soon as the program reaches the next line of code that plays the next audio file.

Comment: I just added it, under Morse Code Mapping class above. Thank you,

Comment: "So it seems to be it skips all of the other wav files executed to the last one." Use [PlaySync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.media.soundplayer.playsync?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Media_SoundPlayer_PlaySync) instead of `Play()`.

Comment: Will do, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, as others suggested, you can use `SoundPlayer.Playasync()` to play all the wav files.

For your second question, you need to use `_morseAlphabetDictionary[character].MorseLetter` to add the correct letter to the stringbuilder.

Here is code example you can refer to.

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IntializeDictionary();
            Console.WriteLine("Please input word");
            string input = GetUserInput();
            Console.WriteLine(Translate(input));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static Dictionary<char, MorseMapping> _morseAlphabetDictionary = new Dictionary<char, MorseMapping>()
            { {'a',new  MorseMapping(".-", Path.Combine("D:\\","1.wav")) },
              { 'b', new MorseMapping("-...", Path.Combine("D:\\","2.wav")) },
              { 'c', new MorseMapping("-.-.", Path.Combine("D:\\","3.wav")) }
               //.. here goes  the rest
            };
        private static void IntializeDictionary()
        {
            _morseAlphabetDictionary['a'].Player.PlaySync();
            _morseAlphabetDictionary['b'].Player.PlaySync();
            _morseAlphabetDictionary['c'].Player.PlaySync();
        }
        public static string GetUserInput()
        {
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            {
                input = input.ToLower();
            }
            return input;
        }

        public static string Translate(string input)
        {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (char character in input)
            {
                if (_morseAlphabetDictionary.ContainsKey(character))
                {
                    stringBuilder.Append(_morseAlphabetDictionary[character].MorseLetter + " ");
                }
                else if (character == ' ')
                {
                    stringBuilder.Append("/ ");
                }
                else
                {
                    stringBuilder.Append(character + " ");
                }
            }
            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }
    public class MorseMapping
    {
        public string MorseLetter { get; set; }
        public SoundPlayer Player { get; set; }

        public MorseMapping(string letter, string filePath)
        {
            this.MorseLetter = letter;
            this.Player = new SoundPlayer(filePath);
            this.Player.LoadCompleted += Player_LoadCompleted;
        }

        private void Player_LoadCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Player.IsLoadCompleted)
            {
                this.Player.PlaySync();
            }
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: It seems to be working yes. Will update if any more trouble, thanks very much.